# When LOAD DATA INFILE INTO TABLE, what if BINARY(100) contains the separator byte?

Tags: mysql, load

I have found experimentally that MySQL first does a split of a row into fields based on the predefined separator. However what if I am loading a binary(100), and somewhere within the BINARY there is the separator byte?

For instance, you have a separator of a tab char (0x9).

What if the binary consists of (worst case) all 0x9 characters?

Answer (score 0):

When you export data , MySQL will escape that data so you can safely insert it again.

If you are the one generating the data to import, you have to be careful and escape it. Prepend a \ to bytes that means a tab, newline or a \ itself that occurs within the data.¨

The details should be on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)